# node.js send http request with temporary /etc/hosts setting

Tags: node.js, hosts

[`/etc/hosts`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183176/what-is-the-use-of-etc-hosts) file allows us to specify an ip address for a domain.

For example, if the content of `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com
```

It means that `www.mydomain.com` represents `127.0.0.1` when you type `www.mydomain.com` in the browser URL bar.

Is it possible to specify a domain for an ip address when sending requests with [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) without modifying `/etc/hosts`?

I work on a public ubuntu machine where many people get access to `/etc/hosts` file. So it's best not to modify `/etc/hosts`.

The [options](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) parameter does not support this feature.

And I don't want to use [hostile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostile) because it changes `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use your own `http.Agent` *or* `createConnection()`. For example:

```
function customLookup(hostname, options, callback) {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options;
    options = null;
  }
  // TODO: check `options` for options like `all` and `family`
  if (hostname.toLowerCase() === 'www.mydomain.com')
    return callback(null, '127.0.0.1');
  return dns.lookup(hostname, options, callback);
}

function createConnection(opts) {
  opts.lookup = customLookup;
  return net.createConnection(opts);
}

http.get({
  // ...
  createConnection
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your `http.Agent` config. For example, when using `node-request`, you can set `option.agentOptions` with `{host: ${ip}}`, before which you should judge the request's host and write a host/ip map file in advance.